# Array does not run in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Whats wrong in this code? I'm trying to check if uyeadi already exists in the database. But its result Array() on giris.php and when I use already taken username and clicked button on kayit.php it send me to anasayfa.php

Uyeler.php controller->

```
public function giris(){
    $uyeadi=$this->input->post('uyeadi');
    $uyesifre=$this->input->post('uyesifre');
    $this->load->model('Uyeler_model');
    $sonuc = $this->Uyeler_model->uyevarmi($uyeadi,$uyesifre);
    print_r($sonuc);
}
```

Uyeler_model.php->

```
function uyevarmi($uyeadi,$uyesifre){
    $result=$this
    ->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('uyeler')
    ->where('uyeadi',$uyeadi)
    ->where('uyesifre',md5($uyesifre))
    ->get()
    ->result();
    return $result;
}

result->
Array ( )
```

Comment: Man, it means no rows is matched according to your query.

Comment: how? i have datas in uyeadi and uyesifre tables on my database

Comment: print query and then run check that if query is Ok.

echo $this->db->last_query();

Answer (score 0):

```
function uyevarmi($uyeadi,$uyesifre){
$result=$this
->db
->select('*')
->from('uyeler')
->where(['uyeadi'=>$uyeadi,'uyesifre'=>md5($uyesifre)])
->get()
->result();
return $result;
}
```

Comment: To improve the quality of this Answer, please include an explanation of what is wrong with the Questioner's code and how your Answer fixes their problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function uyevarmi($uyeadi,$uyesifre){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('uyeler');
    $this->db->where('uyeadi', $uyeadi);
    $this->db->where('uyesifre', md5($uyesifre));
    $query = $this->db->get();
   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```